# Wrong styling after building

Tags: astrojs

I created some pages with tailwind (successfully checked with `npm run astro info`: Integrations @astrojs/tailwind. `tailwind.config.cjs` is there).

With `npm run dev` they look great.

With `npm run build` and than `npm run preview` it looks great, too.

But if I open the files directly (`index.html`) it looks ugly.

I found out that the stylesheets are linked in a wrong way:

The stylesheet in `appname/pageexample/index.html` is defined as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_astro/example.92d61713.css" />
```

But it should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./_astro/example.92d61713.css" />
```

or

How can I tell astro to do it right?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add more details? What do you mean by "looking great" and "ugly"? What code did you get and what did you expect instead? A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem but still can't solve it. I edit it.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue with incorrect stylesheet links when opening the files directly (index.html), you can update the base path used by Astro for building and serving the application. Astro uses the **base** property in the astro.config.mjs file to specify the base path. By default, the base property is set to **"/"**, but in your case, you need to set it to "./" to resolve the stylesheet links correctly when opening the files directly.

Here's how you can do it:

Create or modify the **astro.config.mjs** file in your project root directory if it doesn't already exist.

Inside the **astro.config.mjs** file, set the base property to "./":

```
export default {
  // Other configuration options
  base: "./",
};
```

Save the file and then rebuild the project using **npm run build**.

Now, the stylesheet links in the generated HTML files should use "./_astro/example.92d61713.css" instead of "/_astro/example.92d61713.css", and the styles should be applied correctly when you open the files directly.

Comment: Thank you for this option. But with base: './' I get "/./_astro/example.92d61713.css" - the first / is inserted so that it doesn't work.

Comment: With base: "appname" it works.